# Python Subprocess - Redirect stdout/err to two places

Tags: python, redirect, subprocess, stdout

I have a small python script which invokes an external process using `subprocess`. I want to redirect stdout and stderr to both a log file and to the terminal.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with [`subprocess.PIPE`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE).

You can find [some sample code here](http://blog.kagesenshi.org/2008/02/teeing-python-subprocesspopen-output.html).